# Header doesn't show on load, but shows on refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a phone application which has multiple pages with the same header on each page. However, the header doesn't seem to show unless i refresh the page. Below are my codes:

common js:

```
function printheader() {
    $("#header").append('<h1><img src="images/logo2.png"></h1>');
    $("#header").append("<a href='#' id='btnHome' class='ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left'>Home</a><a href='#' id='btnLogout' data-icon='power' class='ui-btn-right'>Logout</a>");

    $("#btnHome").bind("click", function () {
        window.location = "me.html";
    });

    $("#btnLogout").bind("click", function () {
        localStorage.removeItem("userid");
        localStorage.removeItem("password");
        window.location = "index.html";
    });
}
```

js for each individual page:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function () {
    printheader();
});
```

html per individual page:

```
<div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed" id="header">
</div>
```

Do let me know if there's anything else you need to know!

Thanks

Comment: Where you put your scripts？ In the `<head>` or before the `</body>`?

Comment: try pagecreate instead of pagebeforecreate

Comment: @JiangangXiong my scripts are in the body

Comment: @rajthakur i tried it doesnt work :(